# Set the custom initial date on FullCalendar based on a field in the current node

Tags: javascript

I would like to populate the *custom initial date* based on a field in the current node. Is this possible?

[image]
([bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMM6O.png))

### Update after looking at the module code

I snooped around the module code and noticed the line below.

```
if (!empty($settings['times']['default_date'])) {
    $settings['date'] = $settings['times']['date'];
}
```

[image]
([bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPI0N.png))

### Update 2: Hard coded test

Well this looks possible, I hard coded a test and it appears to have worked. The next step is to pull this value from a Node Field.

```
 // First, use the default date if set.
  dsm($settings['times']);
  if (!empty($settings['times']['default_date'])) {
    //$settings['date'] = $settings['times']['date'];
    $settings['date'] = array(
      'year'=>2012,
      'month'=>1,
      'day'=>2
    );
  }
```

*Edit from file ./includes/fullcalendar.fullcalendar.inc near line 629*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this and two additional Content Node Fields edit worked for me. Starting around line 629 in `includes/views/fullcalendar.fullcalendar.inc`, I changed to the following. Don't forget to add two additional fields to your Content Type with machine names **`field_default_calendar_year`** and **`field_default_calendar_month`**.

Update on project's issues list: [Patch Submitted, Requested Review](http://drupal.org/node/1823192)

See Patch code: http://drupal.org/files/fullcalendar-7.x-2.x-custom_init_date_1.patch